# Looking for extensive world population time series including both data and estimates

Tags: demographics

Does anyone know of a source for whole-world population data, including extrapolated estimates for the times before whole-world demographic records are available?

Comment: How far back do you want the data to go? The World Bank provides reasonable estimates back to 1960 (which you can download here: https://numeracy.co/standard-library/world-population/total), but it sounds like you're looking for a lot more years.

Comment: what about the gapminder data. See https://www.gapminder.org/data/

Comment: Maybe check out Quandl's collection under demography? See https://www.quandl.com/collections/demography/total-population-by-country Quandl also has a database from the Earth Policy Institute with data on population. See https://www.quandl.com/data/EPI?keyword=world%20population. [Disclosure: I work for Quandl]

Comment: I assume https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population_estimates does not suffice for your purposes?

Answer (score 2):

The World Bank Data is from 1960 and is the best open dataset I'm aware of for this. Are you looking for older datasets, or for specific attributes for each country?